# What date format is this in? (PHP Codeigniter File Helper)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to work out what format this date is in!

```
  'date' => int 1342640973
```

Date today is 18.07.2012

I got it from the get_file_info function in the CI File Helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's a *[unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)*!

The value you have represent a date/time in seconds since the first of January 1970 (in UTC), it's often referred to as a "unix timestamp" because of it's origin.

Handling this time representation is easily done in PHP, there are native functions made to convert back and to the format.

---

[`time ()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) will return the current time in the format specified (*unix timestamp*), to convert this into a readable string you can use [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with the appropriate format-string, as in the below example:

```
$unix_timestamp = 1342640973;
$now_utimestamp = time (); 

print_r (
  array (
    date ("Y-m-d G:i:s", $unix_timestamp),
    date ("Y-m-d G:i:s", $now_utimestamp)
  )
);
```

<sup>output on my system:</sup>

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-07-18 21:49:33
    [1] => 2012-07-18 22:18:43
)
```

---

Unless you have told PHP which timezone it's currently in (using php.ini or equivalent) you'll need to specify this using the function [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), passing it the value of  [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) will try to set it according to your system preferences.

If it's unable to find a correct match *UTC* will be used per default.

Comment: I think you want `Y-m-d G:i`. Using `Y-m-d G:s` would probably be a bit useless.

Answer (score 3):

It's a unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds.

To get the current timestamp in PHP, you can use [time](http://php.net/time) and to convert a timestamp into a human-readable format you can use [date](http://php.net/date).

Comment: fyi, that makes it GMT: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 19:49:33 GMT

Comment: Timestamps don't have time zone information. When converting it back into a human readable format, PHP uses the timezone returned from `date_default_timezone_get()`.

Comment: @Mike GMT is a synonym for UTC; DST in the UK is BST.

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter use

```
unix_to_human(TIMESTAMP)
```

to get the human readable date, it will require to include date helper